# Best method to "fork" observable

Tags: angular, rxjs, rxjs5

I need to set the `currentUser: BehaviorSubject<>()` every time the http auth API returns an authorized user. Right now I'm using `do` to send the new user into the `BehaviorSubject` but it seems like a dirty way to accomplish such a task.

Is there a fork method or something similar that will update an observer and return the original observable?

**What I have**

```
public currentUser: BehaviorSubject<any> = new BehaviorSubject<any>(null);

authUser(email: String, password: String) {
  return this.http.post('api.com/auth', {
    email: email,
    password: password
  })
  .do(user => this.currentUser.next(user))
}
```

***What I want***

```
return this.http.post('api.com/auth', {
  email: email,
  password: password
})
.fork(this.currentUser)
```

Comment: but the only way to update a `Subject` is via the method `next()` isn't it

Comment: Do you need to use `behaviorSubject` why cant you just use an observable directly from the http method ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are different ways to tackle this problem but in my opinion you should use `subscribe` instead of `do` and `authUser` should not return anything.  Why have two ways to access the same thing (the current user)?

```
//private field and getter are optional but allows you to expose the
//field as an observable and not a subject
private _currentUser: BehaviorSubject<any> = new BehaviorSubject<any>(null);

get currentUser(): Observable<any> {
  return this._currentUser;
}

authUser(email: String, password: String): void {
  this.http.post('api.com/auth', {
    email: email,
    password: password
  })
  .subscribe(user => this._currentUser.next(user))
}
```

If you want to do cleanup (it is an asynchronous operation so you may want to know when it is done) you could do:

```
authUser(email: String, password: String): Observable<void> {
  let requestObs = this.http.post('api.com/auth', {
    email: email,
    password: password
  }).shareReplay();
  requestObs.subscribe(user => this._currentUser.next(user));
  return requestObs.map(user => null);
}
```

And of course, if you really want the return value you can just drop that last map statement.  In the end it isn't really much different than your `do`.

Comment: Well I think returning an auth observable makes sense in that you can perform any cleanup/transitions for the user after they login and be sure the action spawned from that exact authentication cycle. Thanks though, I just thought that the use case might be common enough to have it's own solution, apparently not

Comment: Sorry, I added a few more examples but I don't think any operator exists with exactly the syntax you want.  `shareReplay` will have basically the same end result as `do` except the caller doesn't have to subscribe to trigger the call.